# Hosting HTML page with mp4 video in IIS 8 not working with hostname

Tags: html, mp4, iis-8, f5

I have a simple html page with video element that plays a video file of mp4 extension. I hosted the page in IIS 8. The MIME Type is configured correctly by default. If I browse using the server name it works fine but when I use the hostname the video does not play. The domain is from Godaddy and it is pointing to our public IP and then we have a load balancer that directs the requests to the two nodes servers.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Open your browser's Developer Tools and check what it's requesting exactly, and what HTTP return code is sent back from the server (404 ? 403 ? else ?..)

Comment: could you share where is your video file is located and did you set the absolute path or relative path in your page? did you get any error message?

Comment: @EugèneAdell, I used fiddler to trace the request and what I found there is no response from the server and after a long time I get an error in the console says error connection reset

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, the file is located on the hard disk next to the html page and I tried both relative and absolute path

Comment: If you change your video extension to one that you know is working (.html it seems), do you get an answer or again ending with a timeout ?

Comment: what is the size of your video file? could you share your video file element code? you are using http or https protocol? did you try to sue different browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to resolve and access the server by server name then you must be calling the server from the internal network and are likely resolving to the internal IP address.

When you are calling the domain name then this will likely be resolving the public IP address from the DNS server where the A record is being hosted - GoDaddy.

```
ping <server name>
ping <dns name>
```

In order to test, please update your hosts file with the DNS name resolving to the internal IP address.

```
%WinDir%\System32\Drivers\Etc

<internal IP address>  fqdns.com
```

If you try to call an external IP address being provided by a DNS server (GoDaddy) it is probably located on your firewall. Your connection will likely be dropped by the firewall due to anti-spoofing rules.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Dawson, It is indeed a security policy issue and it was resolved by our security team. We tried your suggested edit for host file and it worked